# Concurrent Processes and Random Integers

Tags: c, random, concurrency, process

I'm working on an assignment for a class and am tasked with writing a program that creates 4 child process that run concurrently. Each child process must generate an array of 70 elements and display them in lines of 10 each. For some reason it's not working. All of the elements in the array are the same number (+100 for each child), ie. a1[0] = 102, a2[0] = 202, a3[0] = 302, a4[0] = 402. Can someone explain to me why this is the case? Thanks.

```
// include files
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// constants
#define LENGTH 70

// function prototypes
int generateArray(int[], int, int);
int quicksort(int[], int, int);
int printArray(int[]);


int generateArray(int array[LENGTH], int min, int max){
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
    array[i] = (rand()%(max - min + 1))+ min;
  }
  return 0;
}

int quicksort (int x[LENGTH],int first, int last){
  int pivot, j, temp, i;
  if(first<last){
    pivot=first;
    i=first;
    j=last;

    while(i<j){
      while(x[i]<=x[pivot]&&i<last)
    i++;
      while(x[j]>x[pivot])
    j--;
      if(i<j){
    temp=x[i];
    x[i]=x[j];
    x[j]=temp;
      }
    }

    temp=x[pivot];
    x[pivot]=x[j];
    x[j]=temp;
    quicksort(x,first,j-1);
    quicksort(x,j+1,last); 
  }
}

int printArray (int array[LENGTH]){
  int i, sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
    printf("%d ",array[i]);
    sum += array[i];
    if ((i+1)%10 == 0){
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

int main (){
  pid_t child1, child2, child3, child4;
  int sum1=0, sum2=0, sum3=0, sum4=0, sum=0;
  int a1[LENGTH], a2[LENGTH], a3[LENGTH], a4[LENGTH];
  if(!(child1 = fork())){
    //child 1
    generateArray(a1,100,199);
    quicksort(a1,0,LENGTH-1);
    sum1 = printArray(a1);
    printf("Child 1 Sum: %d.\n",sum1);
  } else if (!(child2 = fork())){
    ///child 2
    generateArray(a2,200,299);
    quicksort(a2,0,LENGTH-1);
    sum2 = printArray(a2);
    printf("Child 2 Sum: %d.\n",sum2);
  } else if (!(child3 = fork())){
    //child 3
    generateArray (a3,300,399);
    quicksort(a3,0,LENGTH-1);
    sum3 = printArray(a3);
    printf("Child 3 Sum %d.\n",sum3);
  } else if (!(child4 = fork())){
    //child 4
    generateArray(a4,400,499);
    quicksort(a4,0,LENGTH-1);
    sum4 = printArray(a4);
    printf("Child 4: Sum %d.\n",sum4);
  } else { 
    //parent
  }
  return 0;    
}
```

On an unrelated note, the question asks whether or not the parent can display a sum of all of the elements in all arrays. I don't think that this is possible because processes do not share memory and cannot communicate with each other without the use of pipes, which my prof explicitly stated that we're not allowed to use. Is that right?

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. Otherwise SO looses the possibility to be searched by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rand()` is only a pseudo-random-number generator. If you don't "seed" its state, all processes necessarily produce the same sequence. Look up your manual page for `srand()`. You should call that in your `main` function after the calls to `fork` to set it to more random initial state. Be sure to choose a seed that is different for all your processes.